# What should I think about these unique certificate serial numbers

Tags: authentication, provable-security, authenticated-encryption, certificates

I  was looking at the serial numbers of the certificates for www.google.com and wordpress.com.  Wordpress was listed by openssl as:

04:0B:D4:F8:25:88:C5

This serial is listed as the serial for both my specific wordpress.com domain and for www.wordpress.com.  A google search using the serial number as a keyword shows only my wordpress.com domain (because I pasted the serial number into one of my pages) in the results.  I would expect to find  other hits on Google.

The site www.google.com was listed by openssl as:

5F:BB:FC:7C:4C:6E:FF:92

That serial number, in a google search, showed up with only two listings, mine (Because I again pasted the serial number into a page) and cryptostorm.org.

I would think these numbers would have been put on the google search engine, and yield (probably) many hits.

@cpast:  I'm not downvoting your answer, but I need a better one.  I can see that google indexes the serial numbers and that is obvious if you type or copy the serials I've provided (above) into the google search bar. Using fingerprints as a search term, I can normally see many items in a search result.

And - I know people often cut and paste whole certificate info pages from Firefox, and put them into forum posts, where they ask "What's this?" or "Why's this?"

Additionally, the statement that nobody cares seems silly. One of the first items in the certificate is the serial, and certificate revocation lists are indexed by certificate serial numbers. Those serial numbers are very important.  Your answer seems trollish.  Anyone else?

@SOJPM: Serial numbers are unique within a CA.  This serial number (e.g. Wordpress) - is supposedly used by hundreds of thousands of Wordpress associated domains.  It should have google indexed data associated with it. Unless I have a "special" one.

@cygnusv: No offense taken.

@all: Why can I edit cpast's comment? I'm new to stackexchange.  Seems odd.

@SOJPM: Thanks, and yes that's what I meant.

@truthserum:  Here's the expiry:

issued  on            : 2014-04-14 18:09:05
  expires on            : 2015-10-14 11:29:26

So, it's been around awhile (if what I see is valid) and should have been the cert for a lot (millions?) of users.  I'm not sure how many users WP has.

Maybe someone else can dump the cert or look at the Firefox Cert GUI - and see if the serials match what I have?

Comment: What is your specific question? "What should I think about *X*?" is not really something we can answer here. See our [help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information about asking good questions.

Comment: So you're asking: "Why is this specific serial number used twice?" I'm not exactly sure if serial numbers need to be globally unique. It may be sufficient for them to be unique in the context of the issuing CA and hence it may be the case that the specified domains use different CA and hence can differentiate the certificates.

Comment: Ronald, the answer from cpast is perfectly fine. Don't take it from the wrong side, it is what it is. There aren't more hits in Google because there aren't more indexed websites that talk about it

Comment: you probably mean: "@all, why can I edit cpast's answer?..." Well, you can't really edit it. Your edits won't be applied immediately, but rather need to be reviewed by someone with 1000+ rep. If you've got 1000+ rep you can edit any question/answer without review.

Comment: The fingerprints are also short, 64-bits is not enough to really assume uniqueness. Is it? Also, these seems to expire pretty much annually, meaning new certificates will be issued regularly.

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=wordpress.com

Comment: Common name: *.wordpress.com
SANs: *.wordpress.com, wordpress.com
Valid from April 14, 2014 to October 14, 2015
Serial Number: 1138909231024325 (0x40bd4f82588c5)

Answer (score 4):

> I would think these numbers would have been put on the google search engine, and yield (probably) many hits.

This assumption is wrong. Certificate serial numbers are not indexed by common search engines, nor are they typically posted to any HTML site. Frankly, I'm not sure why you *would* assume they'd be indexed.

The Wordpress certificate is used for all Wordpress domains; it is for `*.wordpress.com` (matching all subdomains of `wordpress.com`), and has `wordpress.com` as an alternate name (so it also works there). The Google certificate you list is only used for `www.google.com`; it is again something that commonly shows up (Chrome reports a different certificate for some reason).

The reason you don't find any posts about them on Google is that no one really cares.